# How to access Windows 10 Recovery Environment (winRE) (ex to start in safe mode)

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, safe-mode, recovery

On [support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode), I have found these steps but it not working. When I hold the power button, my computer shut down directly.

Answer (score 1):

OK this was a bit tricky because I have set a password for my hard drive in boot men. These are the 2 way to access WinRE (my computer is a Dell so I use the Dell logo as a reference ):

**● via Shift + F8:**
Start computer, as soon as I see the Dell logo, I press Shift + F8: if the shortcut was successful, I see "Wait" under the Windows logo

**● by shutting down Windows twice just when it starts:**

1) Shut down computer

2) Start computer, wait for the Dell logo, enter hard drive password then wait for Windows Logo.

3) Once the little dots starts turning under the Windows Logo, press and hold the power button until the computer shut down (it should take about 5-10 seconds)

4) Redo step 2 and 3 then restart your computer. When the Windows logo appear you should see "Preparing automatic repair".

Answer (score -1):

You can restart with Shift Restart to get into Safe Mode.

If the machine is OFF, press start and immediately press F8 repeatedly to get into Safe Mode.

I use this on my own laptop

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. F8 didn't work on my Windows 10 computer. "Shift Restart to get into Safe Mode" is a great way but I wasn't able to log in Windows: after start up, I was stuck in an update loop that ended up on a blue screen of death.